# How do I clip a ring within canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, clipping

I'm trying to create a ring that is divided equally into five parts. My method may be unorthodox as I'm new to JS/JQuery.
Below is the code I have:

```
var c=document.getElementById("c");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(430,430,300,0,2*Math.PI,true);//x-y-r-angle-PI-rotation(clockwise vs anti//
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(430,430,200,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.clip();


var drawAngledLine = function(x, y, length, angle) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length * Math.sin(radians);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.lineWidth = "1";

drawAngledLine(430, 430, 300, -90);
drawAngledLine(430, 430, 300, -162);
drawAngledLine(430, 430, 300, -234);
drawAngledLine(430, 430, 300, -306);
drawAngledLine(430, 430, 300, -18);

ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(430,430,200,0,2*Math.PI,true);
ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
ctx.stroke();
```

I've tried to use ctx.clip();
but it clips the insides of the lines and I want it to mask the inside and only show connecting lines between the inside circle and the outside circle. It's hard to explain without images...

Please can someone help.
Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it a few ways. First you draw the circle with the slices, then you draw a circle over top of it the same color as the background which makes it look like a ring rather than a full circle. The other way is the same as above, except you change the canvas global composition to `destination-out` which an actual hole in the canvas, removing that portion of the circle.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/CvnMw)**

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 256;

    function toRadians(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180
    }


    slicedRing(128,128,5,50,20);

    function slicedRing(x,y,sect,r,w){
        var slice = 360/sect;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";

        for(var i = 0; i < sect; i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
            ctx.arc(x,y,50,toRadians(slice*i),toRadians((slice*i)+slice));
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        // either change this to the background color, or use the global composition
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.arc(x,y,w,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();

        // if using the global composition method, make sure to change it back to default.
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    }
```